# webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

As the documentation states, [you can call webdriver.FirefoxProfile()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html?highlight=profile_directory) with the optional argument of `profile_directory` to point to the directory of a specific profile you want the browser to use. I noticed it was taking a long time to run this command, so when I looked into the code, it looked like it was copying the specified profile Problem is, it takes an extremely long time for the profile to copy (something like >30 minutes, didn't have the patience to wait for it to finish.)

I'm using a hybrid of userscripts and selenium to do some automation for me, so to setup a new profile every single time I want to test out my code would be burdensome.

Is the only way to change this behaviour to edit the `firefox_profile.py` itself (if so, what would be the best way to go about it?)?

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73267063/1560821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the current implementation of *GeckoDriver* with *Firefox* using the `FirefoxProfile()` works as follows :

- If case of initiating a *Browsing Session* through a new **Firefox Profile** as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- A new **rust_mozprofile** gets created on the run as follows :

  ```
  1521446301607   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.xFayqKkZrOB8"
  ```
- Of-coarse on a successful closure (i.e. successful invocation of `driver.quit()`) the temporary **rust_mozprofile.xFayqKkZrOB8** gets deleted/destroyed completely.
- Again in case of initiating a *Browsing Session* through an *existing* **Firefox Profile()** as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\moskcpdq.SeleniumTest')
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Similarly a new **rust_mozprofile** gets created on the run as follows :

  ```
  1521447102321   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.2oSwrQwQoby9"
  ```
- Similarly in this case as well on a successful closure (i.e. successful invocation of `driver.quit()`) the temporary **rust_mozprofile.2oSwrQwQoby9** gets deleted/destroyed completely.
- So the *timespan* you are observing is the time needed for a **`FirefoxProfile()`** to scoop out a new **rust_mozprofile**.

Perhaps as per your question timespan for *profile to copy (something like >30 minutes)* is a pure overhead. So it won't be possible to use a *Firefox Profile* without making a copy of `rust_mozprofile`.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium Client* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to  current [**GeckoDriver v0.20.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox Quantum v59.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Firefox* base version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Firefox Quantum*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: None of the "solution" addresses the user's problem:  how to have firefox use a specified profile *without copying* it every time it starts.