# How to use existing login token for telegram web using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, firefox-profile

I'm trying to read telegram messages from https://web.telegram.org with selenium.

When i open https://web.telegram.org in firefox i'm already logged in, but when opening the same page from selenium webdriver(firefox) i get the login page.

I saw that telegram web is not using cookies for the auth but rather saves values in local storage. I can access the local storage with selenium and have keys there such as: "dc2_auth_key", "dc2_server_salt", "dc4_auth_key", ... but I'm not sure what to do with them in order to login(and if i do need to do something with them then why? its the same browser why wont it work the same when opening without selenium?)

To reproduce:

open firefox and login to https://web.telegram.org then run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://web.telegram.org")
# my code is here but is irrelevant since im at the login page.
driver.close()
```

Comment: Selenium will open a new session, you would have to login into the website using selenium. wouldn't make any difference tho.

Comment: @cruisepandey when i completely close firefox and open it again, then go to telegram web im still authenticated, and that is also a new session. so there must be another difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium use of firefox profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247336/selenium-use-of-firefox-profile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open `https://web.telegram.org` manually using *Firefox*, the *Default Firefox Profile* is used. As you login and browse through the website, the websites stores *Authentication Cookies* within your system. As the cookies gets stored within the *local storage* of the *Default Firefox Profile* even on reopening the browsers you are automatically authenticated.

But when *GeckoDriver* initiates a new web browsing session for your tests everytime a temporary new **mozprofile** is created while launching *Firefox* which is evident from the following log:

```
mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.fDJt0BIqNu0n"
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates “rust_mozprofile” directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240)

Once the *Test Execution* completes and `quit()` is invoked the temporary **mozprofile** is deleted in the following process:

```
webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/f84dbafc-4166-4a08-afd3-79b98bad1470 
geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,3,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
Marionette  TRACE   0 -> [0,3,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
Marionette  DEBUG   New connections will no longer be accepted
Marionette  TRACE   0 <- [1,3,null,{"cause":"shutdown"}]
geckodriver::marionette TRACE   <- [1,3,null,{"cause":"shutdown"}]
webdriver::server   DEBUG   Deleting session
geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Stopping browser process
```

So, when you open the same page using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* the cookies which were stored within the *local storage* of the *Default Firefox Profile* aren't accessible and hence you are redirected to the *Login Page*.

---

To store and use the cookies within the *local storage* to get authenticated automatically you need to create and use a **Custom Firefox Profile**.

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356081/webdriver-firefoxprofile-is-it-possible-to-use-a-profile-without-making-a-cop/49358656#49358656)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! copied my profile and point the code there and it works :) B.T.W how did you get these logs? when i run my code i get no logs from the webdriver..

Comment: You need to enable the trace level logs to see these kind of logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can auth using your current data from local storage.
Example:

```
    driver.get(TELEGRAM_WEB_URL);
    LocalStorage localStorage =  ((ChromeDriver) DRIVER).getLocalStorage();
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("dc2_auth_key","<YOUR AUTH KEY>");
    localStorage.setItem("user_auth","<YOUR USER INFO>");
    driver.get(TELEGRAM_WEB_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to extract credential tokens from the browser's local storage, after logging in:

```py
def get_credential_tokens(driver):
    tokens = driver.execute_script(
        "var tokens = {};\
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){\
            tokens[localStorage.key(i)] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));\
            };\
        return tokens;"
    )

    return tokens
```

you can store it in a JSON file or your .env file and read it from there and set it in the browser's local storage as follow:

```py
credentials = load_credentials()

for key, value in credentials.items():
    set_item(key, value)
```

where the `set_item()` function is:

```py
def set_item(driver, key, value):
    driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", key, value)
```

and the `load_credentials()` function is:

```py
def __load_credentials() -> Dict:
    with open("tokens.json", "r") as f:
        credentials = json.load(f)

    return credentials
```

you can also save the credentials in a JSON file this way:

```py
def save_credentials(credentials) -> None:
    with open("tokens.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(credentials, f)
```