# module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'firefoxprofile'

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-profile

I'm doing web scraping using selenium.I have encountered an issue.

```
Python version 3.9.7, window 10
```

Code:

```
url=['https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-large-cap/']

catergories=['Overview','Xperformance','Valuation','Dividends','Margins','Income Statement','Balance Sheet','Oscillator','Trend-Following']

user_agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'

FireFoxDriverPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Drivers','Geckodriver.exe')

FireFoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

FireFoxProfile.set_preference("general.useragent.override",user_agent)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath)

browser.implicitly_wait(7)

url= 'https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-large-cap/'

browser.get(url)
```

**Error:**

```
module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'firefoxprofile'
```

These the new error i got after i change the FirefoxProfile()
Message: 'Geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

to able to use `FirefoxProfile`

You could do

```
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile()
```

and `set_preference` like below:

```
profile.set_preferences("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
```

Comment: C:\Users\HOYAO\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16264/2381267424.py:6: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  FireFoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
C:\Users\HOYAO\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16264/2381267424.py:8: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath)                                                              
These the error i get after chaging FirefoxProfile()       Message: 'Geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'firefoxprofile'
```

...implies that *`selenium.webdriver`* has no such attribute as ***firefoxprofile***

Instead of `firefoxprofile()` it should have been ***FirefoxProfile()***. Effectively your line of code should have been:

> [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) based code block

```
from selenium import webdriver

user_agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'
FireFoxDriverPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Drivers','Geckodriver.exe')
firefoxprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxprofile.set_preferences("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxprofile, executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath)
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358656/7429447)

---

### Update

With [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) `FirefoxProfile()` have been *Deprecated* and with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) to use a *custom profile* you have to use an instance of `Options`.

> You can find a relevant discussion in [DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088853/7429447)

Comment: C:\Users\HOYAO\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16264/2381267424.py:6: DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  FireFoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
C:\Users\HOYAO\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16264/2381267424.py:8: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath)                                                              
These the error i get after chaging FirefoxProfile() Message: 'Geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: @Roclusachieng Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.