# Firefox WebDriver takes forever to start with 28,000+ entries detected in cache?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-profile

I'm trying to launch a specific profile in **Selenium v4** and **Java** using the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path_to_geckdriver);
File firefoxProfileFile = new File(path_to_file);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(firefoxProfileFile);
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

It took **411 seconds** (almost 7 minutes) to load said profile.

When debugging above, I noticed that the folder: `\MyProfile\cache2\entries\` has **28,000** items in it totaling **1+ GB** of data. I deleted all of the items and ran above code again and this time it took (only?) **69 seconds** to load said profile.

My question is:

1. What process is populating this folder with so many garbage entries? How can I prevent FF from populating `\MyProfile\cache2\entries\` with so many entries in the future?
2. While the load time is now much better, is 60 second load time really the fastest I can achieve?

P.S: I am not creating a temporary FF profile, rather I'm loading existing profile from file.

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate a [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *Browsing Context* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) from an existing [*FirefoxProfile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683355/cannot-resolve-constructor-firefoxdriverorg-openqa-selenium-firefox-firefoxprof) the following settings/configurations:

- browser settings
- Extensions
- Bookmarks
- Apps
- Saved Passwords
- Browsing History

are copied from the actual profile directory into a temporary ***rust_mozprofile*** as follows:

```
1521447102321   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\SOS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.2oSwrQwQoby9"
```

Naturally, the more the settings/configurations to be copied the more time is required for the I/O to complete.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356081/webdriver-firefoxprofile-is-it-possible-to-use-a-profile-without-making-a-cop)

However, to reduce the amount of the leftovers from the executions you should always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Appreciate the response. However, two things still remain unclear to me **1)** After deleting cache entries the entire FF folder is around 200 MB. It doesn't take anything close to 60 seconds to copy 200 MB of data on my PC (maybe 3-5 seconds max) **2)** I still don't understand what process is generating so much garbage in `\MyProfile\cache2\entries\`. Is this normal? It's not like I'm browsing thousands of websites with this profile that the cache should be populated like this.

Comment: The amount of the cache may vary between the type of Firefox browser (Mozilla Firefox, Firefox Nightly, Firefox Development, ESR, etc) and the features and functionalities added/removed.