# Adding extension through selenium firefox profile success. But when I open these Firefox manually, the extension still not installed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

I use selenium python. My code work success, the extension was added. But when I close the code, open the Firefox Profile which added extension by manually then the extension isn't installed.
My code

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

try:

```
path = "My_profile_PATH"
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path)     
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

# path to your downloaded Firefox addon extension XPI file

extension_path = "MY_extension_PATH"

# using webdriver's install_addon API to install the downloaded Firefox extension

driver.install_addon(extension_path, temporary=True)

# Opening the Firefox support page to verify that addon is installed

driver.get("about:support")

# xpath to the section on the support page that lists installed extension

addons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),"Add-ons") and not(contains(text(),"with"))]')
# scrolling to the section on the support page that lists installed extension

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", addons)

# introducing program halt time to view things, ideally remove this when performing test automation in the cloud using LambdaTest

print("Success. Yayy!!")

time.sleep(20)
```

except Exception as E:

```
print(E)
```

finally:

```
# exiting the fired Mozilla Firefox selenium webdriver instance

driver.quit()

# End Of Script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask Selenium to use a profile, it copies it to a temporary location and use this copy. So whatever you do doesn't affect the original profile.

If you want your script to affect the original profile, don't ask Selenium to use a profile. Instead, tell Firefox directly which profile to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('-profile')
options.add_argument('/path/to/your/profile')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested for using existing profile directly (without copying to new location) and keeping changes (cache, cookies etc) for next sessions, here's my improved version of Python Selenium 3.14.1 allowing this behavior unlike original Selenium. Here's Github repository with this version: https://github.com/crspl/python-selenium-with-profiles